# Pointer casting and pointer size in C

Tags: c, pointers, casting

Edit: I did not use sizeof() because this is an exercise to test pointer knowledge.

I tried to compute the size of an integer in the following code:

```
  int intArray[10];
  int * intPtr1;
  int * intPtr2;
  int size;
  intPtr1 = intArray;
  intPtr2 = intArray + 1;
  size = (char*)intPtr2 - (char*)intPtr1;
```

Result: size = 4. So far so good, but when I tried to compute the size of a pointer in the following code:

```
  double * ptrArray[10];
  double ** ptrPtr1;
  double ** ptrPtr2;
  ptrPtr1 = ptrArray;
  ptrPtr2 = ptrArray + 1;
  char size;
  size = (char**)ptrPtr2 - (char**)ptrPtr1;    //line 7
  printf("ptrPtr1 = %p, ptrPtr2 = %p, size = %d\n", ptrPtr1, ptrPtr2, size);
```

Result: size = 1

If I change line 7 into below:

```
  size = (char*)ptrPtr2 - (char*)ptrPtr1;    //line 7
```

Result: size = 8

What is the reason for this? Also, why the (char*) casting does not give me the following warning?

```
 warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
```

Comment: Pointer differences are in elements, not bytes (so the byte difference may be 8, but if `sizeof(char *) == 8`, then the difference of two `char **`s will be 1.

Comment: Also, if you want the size of an integer, why not just use `sizeof(int)`?

Comment: Could you elaborate a little bit? I use (char*) to cast in my integer size program (pointer is (int*) type), so I thought I should use (char**) in my pointer size program to match the pointer type (double**). I did not use sizeof because this is a practice for pointers.

Comment: Are you by any chance compiling on a 64 bit system? Then pointer would be 8 bytes but int is usually still 4 bytes.

Comment: `char *` is compatible with every other pointer type (it was used before the `void` keyword and `void *` type were introduced).

Comment: You're casting from an array of pointers to double to an array of pointers to char. In both, you've got an array of pointers, so the elements which fit between two memory addresses is always the same (as long as none of the pointers are to functions, which makes that not necessarily true). Char, on the other hand, is only 1 byte, so you get the number of bytes which fit between those arbitrary memory locations.

Comment: `sizeof(char*)` could be different to `sizeof(double*)` (although on modern systems they seem to be the same)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double * ptrArray[10];
double ** ptrPtr1;
double ** ptrPtr2;
ptrPtr1 = ptrArray;
ptrPtr2 = ptrArray + 1;
char size;
size = (char**)ptrPtr2 - (char**)ptrPtr1;    //line 7
```

You can **not** convert a `double **` to a `char **` in any meaningful way, and this is not what you want anyway. What you want is to convert the pointers to **pointers to characters**, and calculate the difference measured in **characters**:

```
size = (char*)ptrPtr2 - (char*)ptrPtr1;    //line 7
```

The original cast, a `(char **)`, is a pointer to an object. The object in question is a `char *` which typically has a size of 4 or 8. The cast I propose, a `(char *)`, is also a pointer to an object. This time, the object is a `char` which always has the size 1. The difference between two pointers of the first kind are measured in multiples of (typically) 4 or 8, while the second kind are measured in multiples of 1.

```
printf("ptrPtr1 = %p, ptrPtr2 = %p, size = %d\n", ptrPtr1, ptrPtr2, size);
```

The `%p` conversion specifier expects an argument of type `void *`. This is unlikely to cause any practical problems, but you should still cast your pointers to avoid undefined behaviour:

```
printf("ptrPtr1 = %p, ptrPtr2 = %p, size = %d\n", (void *)ptrPtr1, (void *)ptrPtr2, size);
```

And then we get into the realm of the truly bizarre: If you are on a platform where `sizeof (char) == sizeof (int)`, and plain `char` is unsigned, then `size` will be promoted to `unsigned int` which is incompatible with the `signed int` expected by the `%d` conversion specifier, which also invokes undefined behaviour. If that should be the case then, well, let's say you have my sympathy. :-)